# What is the keyboard shortcut in Visual Studio Code to pop up the Quick Fix menu?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, autocorrect

In the Visual Studio Code IDE, when it red squiggle underlines code, how do you pop up the menu to show "Quick Fix" suggestions and choose one of the suggested fixes to apply to your code? Example of underlined code:

[image]

Comment: I use Linux and with right click on a quick-fix availability, I get a pop up with `ctrl+` which is my `zoom`. Can I change this pop up to show `ctrl+.` that works as shortcut.

Answer (score 61):

On the Mac, use the <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> keys to pop up a menu of Quick Fix suggestions.

On Windows, use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> keys.

Then just select the Quick Fix suggestion that you want to apply to your code.

Example on the Mac:

[image]

Comment: In my env, it can't work on windows, how to check whether the shortcut is occupied by other software?

Comment: This short cut seems to be gone in my system - CTRL+. opens the "helping" menu from the top of VSTC

Comment: Is there a way to add a shortcut to one of the suggestions? For example for missing imports.

Answer (score 5):

The one more corresponding to the question is probably `Ctrl+K Ctrl+I`.

[image: showHover shortcut]